# Ionic 3- How to scroll down content on button click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm working on an ionic chat app. I want scroll down content automatically on send text button click. you can check this in images.

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

**Here is my code:**

```
<ion-content scrollDownOnLoad="true" id="chat-window" class="bg" no-padding>

    <ion-list>
        <ion-item text-wrap class="message" *ngFor="let chat of chats" no-lines>
            <div [class]="chat.sent_by == loggedInUserKey ? 'messageRight' : 'messageLeft'">
            <p class="text">{{chat.message}}</p>
            <p [class]="chat.sent_by == loggedInUserKey ? 'datetimeRight' : 'datetimeLeft'">
                <span *ngIf='chat.display_date'>{{chat.date}}</span>
                <span>{{chat.time}}</span>
                <span *ngIf='chat.seen' [class]="chat.sent_by == loggedInUserKey ? 'displayseen' : 'hideseen'">seen</span>
            </p>
           </div>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1):

First import content from ionic-angular

```
 import { Content } from 'ionic-angular';
```

By using `@viewChild` annotation you can get `ion-content` reference in you component page

```
 @ViewChild(Content) chatlist : Content
```

Then in your button click

```
this.chatlist.scrollToBottom();
```

demo [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-kkve6u?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts)

Comment: It is showing an error "Cannot read property 'scrollToBottom' of undefined"

Comment: can you check with the demo link i provided

Comment: Yeah I tried the same, still it is showing the same error "Cannot read property 'scrollToBottom' of undefined".

Answer (score 0):

You can use some DOM Node properties like scrollTop , scrollLeft.

Example:

```
var el = document.querySelector("#chat-window");
el.scrollTop = 0; //this will make window scroll to top (if scroll is there)
el.scrollLeft = 0;
```

But as there are no properties like scrollBottom, scrollRight. (not that I know). So you need to have an account how much scrollTop has to be done for every button click depending upon the content size.

```
el.scrollTop = x; //x is calculated scrollTop value.
```

You can put a hack to assign scrollTop as Infinity to make it scroll to the bottom.

```
el.scrollTop = Infinity;
```

But it's not recommended, there could be some side affects on different browsers with Infinity and scroll update. It's always better to have full control on your code and update the scrollTop whenever needed.

I hope it helps.